# compute average without taking into account max value

Tags: r

I have the following data frame `df`

`ARTNR` = article number (There are redundant article numbers)

```
ARTNR   AMOUNT
20      10
12      10
12      10
20      10
12      100
20      200
...     ...
```

I want to create the data frame `df_delta`

`sum_1` = sum of `AMOUNT` for each `ARTNR` (I want to have one article number, no redundancy)

`sum_minus_max` = `sum_1` - max value of `AMOUNT` for `ARTNR`

`average` = `sum_minus_max` / n - 1, where n is the number of `ARTNR`

`delta` = `average` - maximum value for `AMOUNT` for `ARTNR`

```
 ARTNR   sum_1      sum_minus_max   average   delta
20       220        20              10        -190
12       120        20              10        -90
...      ...        ...             ...       ...
```

Can someone please help me? I would highly appreciate it!

thank you so much!

Comment: What in case there is more than one value equal to max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` like:

```
newDataFrameName <- do.call(cbind, aggregate(AMOUNT ~ ARTNR, df, function(x) {
  sumx <- sum(x)
  maxx <- max(x)
  meanx <- mean(x[x!=maxx])
  c(sum_1=sumx, sum_minus_max=sum(x[x!=maxx]), average=meanx, delta=meanx-maxx)}))
newDataFrameName
#    ARTNR sum_1 sum_minus_max average delta
#[1,]    12   120            20      10   -90
#[2,]    20   220            20      10  -190
```

Comment: Is there a bracket missing? Have you tried this code one my example?

Comment: Oh, yes. The closing `)` was missing. Sorry. Now it should work.

Comment: thank you so much. Is it possible to store the values in a new data frame?

Comment: Yes. Simple write `newDataFrameName <- ` before `aggregate`

Comment: that I have tried but it does not work. There is no error but it simply does not show all the new variables in the new data frame.

Comment: I have one last question: I have added another layer of complexity to my initial question (see above "2 thing:"). Do you know how to implement that in your code? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Maybe it's better if you ask a new question with this new complexity. Otherwise the older answers will not fit the question anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890396/compute-average-without-taking-into-account-max-value-for-a-specific-time-period

Comment: Do you have any idea why the new data frame does not contain the new columns? ARTNR AMOUNT.sum_1 AMOUNT.sum_minus_max AMOUNT.average AMOUNT.delta

Comment: Because it was a list. Now I added `cbind`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr to manipulate the data like that:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ARTNR = c(20,12,12,20,12,20), 
                 AMOUNT = c(10,10,10,10,100,200))

df %>% group_by(ARTNR) %>% summarize(sum_1 = sum(AMOUNT), sum_minus_max = sum(AMOUNT) - max(AMOUNT), 
                  average = (sum(AMOUNT) - max(AMOUNT))/(n()-1), 
                  delta =  (sum(AMOUNT) - max(AMOUNT))/(n()-1) - max(AMOUNT))
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  ARTNR sum_1 sum_minus_max average delta
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1    12   120            20      10   -90
2    20   220            20      10  -190
```

Comment: I have updated my example, I have made a mistake when adding numbers for ARTNR. Do you know how I can execute it?

Comment: I've updated the code and example, although GKI covered it well too.

Answer (score 0):

try the following script:

```
library(dplyr)

remove_max <- function(vector){ 
    # Avoids remove vector with only 1 element
    if(length(vector) == 1) return(vector)
    indx <- which(vector == max(vector))
    vector[-indx]
}

data %>%
    group_by(ARTNR) %>%
    summarize(
        sum_1 = sum(AMOUNT),
        sum_minus_max = sum_1 - max(AMOUNT),
        average = mean(remove_max(AMOUNT)),
        delta = average - max(AMOUNT)
    )
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I have updated my example, I have made a mistake when adding numbers for ARTNR. Do you know how I can execute it?