# compute average without taking into account max value for a specific time period

Tags: r

I have the data frame `df`

```
 ARTNR AMOUNT    DATE
    20  10      01.12.2019
    12  10      15.12.2019
    12  10      05.12.2019
    20  10      20.12.2019
    12  100     01.02.2020
    20  200     15.02.2020
    20  400     31.08.2019
    12  300     15.07.2019
    ... ...     ...
```

I want to exclude max values for a specific time period, namely 01.11.2019 until 01.03.2020.

```
 ARTNR AMOUNT    DATE
    20  10      01.12.2019
    12  10      15.12.2019
    12  10      05.12.2019
    20  10      20.12.2019
    12  100     01.02.2020 --> this is the max value for ARTNR 12
    20  200     15.02.2020 --> this is the max value for ARTNR 20
    20  400     31.08.2019
    12  300     15.07.2019
    ... ...     ...
```

I want to create data frame `df_delta`

```
ARTNR   sum_1   sum_minus_max   average          delta
20      620     420 (620-200)   140 (420/3)      -60 (140-200)
12      420     320 (420-100)   106.66  (320/3)  6.66 (106.66-100)
```

**note**:

**we are subtracting 200 to compute the column `delta` (max value for ARTNR 20 for the time period of interest)**

**we are subtracting 100 to compute the column `delta` (max value for ARTNR 12 for the time period of interest)**

`ARTNR` = article number (There are redundant article numbers)

`sum_1` = sum of `AMOUNT` for each `ARTNR` (I want to have one article number, no redundancy)

`sum_minus_max` = `sum_1` - max value of `AMOUNT` for `ARTNR` **in the time period of interest**

`average` = `sum_minus_max` / n-1 **(I want to exclude the max values)**

`delta` = `average` - maximum value for `AMOUNT` for `ARTNR`**in the time period of interest**

**This is relevant when reading the input from Ian Campbell:**

```
dput(head(df))
structure(list(ARTNR = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 20, 20), AMOUNT = c(10, 
10, 100, 300, 10, 10), DATE = structure(c(1576368000, 1575504000, 
1580515200, 1563148800, 1575158400, 1576800000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `dplyr` and `lubridate`. We use `dmy` for easy parsing of dates into a form we can perform logical comparisons. We group by `ARTNR`, then we use `case_when` to create a `NEWAMOUNT` column that replaces the `AMOUNT` value with `0` when it is the max for the date range. Otherwise `case_when` returns `AMOUNT`.

Then we use `summerize` to calculate the information.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(ARTNR) %>%
  mutate(NEWAMOUNT = case_when(AMOUNT == max(AMOUNT[DATE < dmy("01.03.2020") &
                                                    DATE > dmy("01.11.2019")]) ~ 0,
                               TRUE ~ as.double(AMOUNT))) %>%
  summarize(sum_1 = sum(AMOUNT),
            sum_minux_max = sum(NEWAMOUNT),
            average =  sum(NEWAMOUNT) / (n() - 1),
            delta = average - max(AMOUNT[AMOUNT != NEWAMOUNT]))
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  ARTNR sum_1 sum_minux_max average  delta
#  <int> <int>         <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    12   420           320    107.   6.67
#2    20   620           420    140  -60
```

Comment: thank you so much! This looks promising. I have added some infos in bold to my initial post. I think 2 things must be changed: 1) divide "sum_minus_max" by n-1 (I want to exclude the max value for the time period of interest 2) I want to substract from "average" the max value for the time period of interest ( I think right now your code substracts the overall max value. What I want is the max value that falls in the time period of interst). I hope this is clear, otherwise I have to rephrase it. thank you so much!

Comment: My mistake, sorry for the inconvenience! I have corrected it!! thanks for your time and help!

Comment: damn, actually it does not work. Do you know why? Date is formatted as "unknown". Does that might be the problem?

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  ARTNR sum_1 sum_minux_max average delta
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1    12   420           420    140    Inf
2    20   620           620    207.   Inf

Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: In max(AMOUNT[AMOUNT != NEWAMOUNT]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In max(AMOUNT[AMOUNT != NEWAMOUNT]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!!! Should I delete the output from my question?

Comment: I would suggest to leave it, it helps clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

A Base-R Aproach

```
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE,"%d.%m.%Y")
data_split <- df[df$DATE >= as.Date("01.11.2019","%d.%m.%Y") & df$DATE <= as.Date("01.03.2020","%d.%m.%Y"),]
data_split <- split(data_split$AMOUNT,df$ARTNR)

df_delta <- data.frame(
    ARTNR = names(data_split),
    sum_1 = sapply(data_split, sum))
    df_delta$sum_minus_max <- df_delta$sum_1 - sapply(data_split, max)
    df_delta$average <- sapply(data_split, function(x) mean(x,-max(x)))
    df_delta$delta <- df_delta$average  - sapply(data_split, max)
```

output

```
   ARTNR sum_1 sum_minus_max  average     delta
12    12   120            20 40.00000  -60.0000
20    20   220            20 73.33333 -126.6667
```

Edit: Saw after the fact that you wanted a date range. I have edited it